# NaN gradients in TensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, gradient-descent

I am trying to learn an arbitrary 1D function using neural networks in TensorFlow. Here is my approach so far:

I have a set of fundamental functions, and I want to be able to express any function in terms of the set of fundamental functions. To do this, I introduced four basic transformations as 1) x --> a.x, 2) x --> x^b, 3) f(x) --> {f(x)}^c, 4) f(x) --> d.f(x). I call the set {a, b, c, d} as `params`. My objective is given any function, `g`, I want to be able to find the `params` of the function of the fundamental set such that summing up all the functions in the set with the optimal params gives the closest estimate of `g`. Given the short prelude to my objective, here is my code that I wrote to achieve this.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers
import numpy as np
import warnings
import os
import sys
import getpass
import wandb
import math
from tqdm import trange
from functools import partial
from functions import Function
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import List, Union
from DataLoader import DataLoader
from debugging import *


os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
os.environ['MLIR_CRASH_REPRODUCER_DIRECTORY'] = '1'
os.environ['TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS'] = '1'
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
os.system('clear')
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)

# seed = np.random.randint(0, 1000)
# print(f"seed: {seed}")
# tf.random.set_seed(seed)
tf.random.set_seed(71)


class ParameterNet(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_basis_functions, support, embedding_dim = 128, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.n = num_basis_functions
        self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim
        self.built = False
        # self.basis = basis
        self.support = support

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # print(f"input shape to ParameterNet: {input_shape}")
        assert input_shape[0] == input_shape[1], f"Shape of inp and g_s must be same"
        key_dim, value_dim, query_dim = input_shape[0][-1], input_shape[1][-1], input_shape[2][-1]
        self.attn = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads = 4, key_dim = 64, value_dim = 64)
        self.projection_head = layers.Dense(4, activation = tf.identity)
        self.built = True

    @tf.function
    def __call__(self, inp, g_s, basis, training = None):
        '''
        key = inp, value = g_s, query = basis
        '''
        if not self.built:
            self.build([inp.shape, g_s.shape, basis.shape])
        
        attn_op = self.attn(basis, g_s, inp)

        projected_op = self.projection_head(attn_op)

        norm_op = tf.norm(projected_op)
        noise_stddev = tf.multiply(1e-7, norm_op)

        print(f" PARAMETER == NaN: {tf.reduce_all(tf.math.is_nan(projected_op))}")

        # projected_op = tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(projected_op), tf.random.normal(projected_op.shape, mean = 0, stddev = noise_stddev), projected_op)

        # projected_op = tf.divide(projected_op, tf.norm(projected_op))

        return projected_op

    def call(self, inp, g_s, basis, training = None):
        return self.__call__(inp, g_s, basis, training = training)


    def evaluate(self, list_of_tensors):
        func, inp, inp_power, inp_coeff = list_of_tensors
        assert len(func.shape) == 2, f"func should be a tensor of rank 2 of shape (num_basis_functions, num_samples). Found rank {len(func.shape)}. Full shape received: {func.shape}"
        assert len(inp.shape) == 2, f"inp should be a tensor of rank 2 of shape (num_basis_functions, num_samples). Found rank {len(inp.shape)}. Full shape received: {inp.shape}"
        assert len(inp_power.shape) == 1, f"inp_power should be a tensor of rank 1 of shape (num_basis_functions, ). Found rank {len(inp_power.shape)}. Full shape received: {inp_power.shape}"
        assert len(inp_coeff.shape) == 1, f"inp_coeff should be a tensor of rank 1 of shape (num_basis_functions, ). Found rank {len(inp_coeff.shape)}. Full shape received: {inp_coeff.shape}"

        support = tf.squeeze(self.support)

        inp_power = tf.expand_dims(inp_power, -1)
        inp_coeff = tf.expand_dims(inp_coeff, -1)

        inp = inp_coeff * tf.pow(inp, inp_power)

        def outer_map_min(row):
            def inner_map_min(element):
                return tf.argmin(support - element, output_type = tf.int32)
            return tf.map_fn(inner_map_min, row, parallel_iterations = row.shape[0], dtype = tf.int32)

        indices = tf.map_fn(outer_map_min, inp, parallel_iterations = inp.shape[0], dtype=tf.int32)

        def gather_func_and_indices(func_and_indices):
            func, idx = func_and_indices
            return tf.gather(func, idx, axis = 0)

        g_eval = tf.map_fn(gather_func_and_indices, (func, indices), parallel_iterations = indices.shape[0], dtype = tf.float32)

        return g_eval

    @tf.function
    def reconstruct_from(self, inp, basis, params):
        assert len(params.shape) == 3, f"params must be a rank 3 tensor of shape (num_distinct_params, num_basis_functions, 4); found params.shape = {params.shape}"

        num_distinct_params = params.shape[0]
        num_basis_functions = params.shape[1]

        assert len(inp.shape) == 2, f"inp should be a rank 2 tensor. Found rank {len(inp.shape)}. Full shape received: {inp.shape}"
        assert basis.shape[0] == num_basis_functions, f"shape[0] of basis should be the number of basis functions. Found number of basis functions {num_basis_functions} (inferred from params)"
        assert len(basis.shape) == 2, f"basis should be a rank 2 tensor of shape (num_basis_functions, samples). Found rank {len(basis.shape)}. Full shape received: {basis.shape}"


        inp_tiled = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(inp, 0), [num_basis_functions, 1, 1])
        inp_tiled = tf.squeeze(inp_tiled)
        basis_tiled = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(basis, 0), [num_distinct_params, 1, 1])
        inp_tiled_tiled = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(inp_tiled, 0), [num_distinct_params, 1, 1])
        inp_power = tf.gather(params, 1, axis = 2)
        inp_coeff = tf.gather(params, 0, axis = 2)

        print(f"is_nan(inp_power): {tf.reduce_any(tf.math.is_nan(inp_power)).numpy()}")
        print(f"is_nan(inp_coeff): {tf.reduce_any(tf.math.is_nan(inp_coeff)).numpy()}")

        g_x_scaled = tf.vectorized_map(lambda x: self.evaluate(x), (basis_tiled, inp_tiled_tiled, inp_power, inp_coeff))

        print(f"is_nan(g_x_scaled): {tf.reduce_any(tf.math.is_nan(g_x_scaled)).numpy()}")
        print(f"is_inf(g_x_scaled): {tf.reduce_any(tf.math.is_inf(g_x_scaled)).numpy()}")

        power = tf.expand_dims(params[:, :, 3], -1)
        coeff = tf.expand_dims(params[:, :, 2], -1)

        print(f"is_nan(power): {tf.reduce_any(tf.math.is_nan(power)).numpy()}")
        print(f"is_nan(coeff): {tf.reduce_any(tf.math.is_nan(coeff)).numpy()}")

        g_scaled = tf.multiply(coeff, tf.pow(g_x_scaled, power))

        print(f"is_nan(g_scaled): {tf.reduce_any(tf.math.is_nan(g_scaled)).numpy()}")
        print(f"is_inf(g_scaled): {tf.reduce_any(tf.math.is_inf(g_scaled)).numpy()}")

        g_scaled = tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(g_scaled), tf.zeros_like(g_scaled), g_scaled)
        # g_scaled = tf.where(tf.math.is_inf(g_scaled), tf.ones_like(g_scaled), g_scaled)

        g_scaled = tf.reduce_sum(g_scaled, axis = 1)

        return g_scaled 


    def compile(self, optimizer, **kwargs):
        super().compile(**kwargs)
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.loss = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(name = "mse")
        self.loss_tracker = keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError(name = "mse")
        self.norm_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name = "norm")

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.loss_tracker, self.norm_tracker]

    @tf.function
    def train_step(self, data, g_true):
        inp, basis = data
        num_functions = g_true.shape[0]
        inp_tiled = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(inp, 1), [num_functions, 1, 1])
        basis_tiled = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(basis, 0), [num_functions, 1, 1])
        g = tf.expand_dims(g_true, 1)
        # print(f"{inp_tiled.shape=}, {basis_tiled.shape=}, {g_true.shape=}")
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            params = self(inp_tiled, g, basis_tiled)
            print(f"is_nan(params): {tf.reduce_any(tf.math.is_nan(params)).numpy()}")
            # print(f"is_inf(params): {tf.reduce_any(tf.math.is_inf(params)).numpy()}")

            g_hat = self.reconstruct_from(inp, basis, params)

            print(f"is_nan(g_hat): {tf.reduce_any(tf.math.is_nan(g_hat)).numpy()}")
            # print(f"is_inf(g_hat): {tf.reduce_any(tf.math.is_inf(g_hat)).numpy()}")

            loss = self.loss(g_true, g_hat)
            print(f"loss: {loss}")
        
        # variables = tape.watched_variables()
        variables = self.trainable_variables
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, variables)

        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, variables))
        self.loss_tracker.update_state(g_true, g_hat)
        self.norm_tracker.update_state(tf.linalg.norm(g_hat))

        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}


    def yield_batches(self, g: np.ndarray, batch_size: int):
        # print(f"g shape: {g.shape}")
        num_g = len(g)
        for i in range(0, num_g, batch_size):
            yield g[i:i+batch_size, :]



    def fit(self, inp: np.ndarray, 
                  g: np.ndarray, 
                  basis: np.ndarray, 
                  epochs = 10, batch_size = 256,
                  epoch_offset = 0) -> None:
        
        num_batches = np.ceil(len(g) / batch_size).astype(np.int32)

        for epoch in range(epoch_offset, epochs + epoch_offset):
            pbar = trange(num_batches, ascii = " >=", bar_format = "{desc}: {percentage:3.0f}%|{bar}|{n_fmt}/{total_fmt} [ETA {remaining}] | {postfix}")
            pbar.set_description(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs + epoch_offset}")
            for g_batch in self.yield_batches(g, batch_size):
                metrics = self.train_step([inp, basis], g_batch)
                pbar.set_postfix_str(f"mse: {metrics['mse'].numpy():.5f}, norm: {metrics['norm'].numpy():.5f}")
                pbar.update(1)

            # save g_hat occasionally

            if all([(epoch) % 10 == 0]) or epoch + 1 == epochs + epoch_offset or epoch == epoch_offset:
                g_hat = self.predict(inp, g, basis, batch_size)
                np.save(f"./g/g_hat_at_epoch_{epoch+1}.npy", g_hat)
                self.save_weights(f"./Weights/epoch_{epoch+1}", save_format = 'tf')

    def predict(self, inp: np.ndarray,
                      g: np.ndarray,
                      basis: np.ndarray,
                      batch_size: int) -> np.ndarray:

        g_hat = []
        num_batches = np.ceil(len(g) / batch_size).astype(np.int32)
        pbar = trange(num_batches)
        pbar.set_description("predicting...")
        for g_batch in self.yield_batches(g, batch_size):
            num_functions = g_batch.shape[0]
            inp_tiled = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(inp, 1), [num_functions, 1, 1])
            basis_tiled = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(basis, 0), [num_functions, 1, 1])
            g = tf.expand_dims(g_batch, 1)
            params = self(inp_tiled, g, basis_tiled, training = False)
            g = tf.expand_dims(g_batch, 1)
            g_hat.append(self.reconstruct_from(inp, basis, params))
            pbar.update(1)
        
        g_hat = tf.concat(g_hat, axis = 0)

        # print(f"g_hat shape: {g_hat.shape}")

        return g_hat



def ParameterNet_call_test_1():
    n = 10      # number of functions whose params to be estimated
    i = 100     # input length
    s = 1000    # support length
    support = np.linspace(-50, 50, s, endpoint = True, dtype = np.float32).reshape([1, -1])     # support shape: [1, s]
    x = support[:, 500:500 + i]         # x shape: [1, i]
    basis = np.random.random((16, s))   # basis shape: [16, s]
    g_s = np.random.random((n, i))      # g shape: [n, i]

    inp = np.tile(x, [n, 1])    # inp shape: [n, i]

    # make inp(key) dimension as [B, S, dim]
    inp = np.expand_dims(inp, 1)    # inp shape: [n, 1, i]

    # make g_s(value) dimension as [B, S, dim]
    g_s = np.expand_dims(g_s, 1)    # g_s shape: [n, 1, i]

    # make basis(query) dimension as [B, T, dim]
    basis = np.expand_dims(basis, 1)        # basis shape: [16, 1, s]
    basis = np.transpose(basis, [1, 0, 2])  # basis shape: [1, 16, s]
    basis = np.tile(basis, [n, 1, 1])       # basis shape: [n, 16, s]

    pnet = ParameterNet(num_basis_functions = 16, support = support)
    params = pnet(inp, g_s, basis)      # key = inp, value = g_s, query = basis
    print(params.shape)


def ParameterNet_reconstruct_test_1():
    n = 10      # number of functions whose params to be estimated
    i = 100     # input length
    s = 1000    # support length
    support = np.linspace(-50, 50, s, endpoint = True, dtype = np.float32).reshape([1, -1])     # support shape: [1, s]
    x = support[:, 500:500 + i]         # x shape: [1, i]
    basis = np.random.random((16, s))   # basis shape: [16, s]
    g_s = np.random.random((n, i))      # g shape: [n, i]

    inp = x # inp shape: [1, i]

    params = np.random.random((n, 16, 4))

    pnet = ParameterNet(num_basis_functions = 16, support = support)

    g_hat = pnet.reconstruct_from(inp, basis, params)

    print(g_hat.shape)

def ParameterNet_predict_test_1():
    dl = DataLoader('./train_data.npy', './basis.npy')
    params, datas, basis = dl.load()

    # n = 64
    # s = 10000
    # num_basis_fn = 16

    # print(params.shape, datas.shape, basis.shape)
    g_s = datas.reshape([-1, datas.shape[-1]])  # g_s shape: [1008, 10000]

    support = np.linspace(-50, 50, 10000, endpoint = True, dtype = np.float32).reshape([1, -1])     # support shape = [1, 10000]

    l = np.argmin((support-(-5))**2)
    h = np.argmin((support-5)**2)
    
    inp = support[:, l:h]
    g_s = g_s[:, l:h]

    print(f"g shape: {g_s.shape}")

    pnet = ParameterNet(num_basis_functions = datas.shape[1], embedding_dim = 128, support = support)
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 1e-2)
    pnet.compile(optimizer = optimizer)
    try:
        g_hat = pnet.predict(inp, g_s, basis, batch_size = 128)
        print(g_hat.shape)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(f"Operation Ended by {getpass.getuser()}")


def TrainParameterNet(batch_size = 256, epochs = 10, epoch_offset = 0, checkpoint_path = None):
    dl = DataLoader('./train_data.npy', './basis.npy')
    params, datas, basis = dl.load()

    # n = 64
    # s = 10000
    # num_basis_fn = 16

    # print(params.shape, datas.shape, basis.shape)
    g_s = datas.reshape([-1, datas.shape[-1]])  # g_s shape: [1008, 10000]

    support = np.linspace(-50, 50, 10000, endpoint = True, dtype = np.float32).reshape([1, -1])     # support shape = [1, 10000]

    l = np.argmin((support-(-5))**2)
    h = np.argmin((support-5)**2)
    
    inp = support[:, l:h]
    g_s = g_s[:, l:h]

    pnet = ParameterNet(num_basis_functions = datas.shape[1], embedding_dim = 128, support = support)
    if epoch_offset != 0:
        assert checkpoint_path is not None, f"If epoch_offset is not 0 then checkpoint_path must not be None"
        epoch_offset = int(checkpoint_path.split('_')[-1])
        inp_shape = [16, 1, h-l]
        basis_shape = [16, 16, datas.shape[-1]]
        g_s_shape = [16, 1, h-l]
        pnet.build([inp_shape, g_s_shape, basis_shape])
        pnet.load_weights(filepath = checkpoint_path)
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 1e-2)
    pnet.compile(optimizer = optimizer)
    try:
        pnet.fit(inp = inp, g = g_s, basis = basis, 
                 epochs = epochs, batch_size = batch_size, 
                 epoch_offset = epoch_offset)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(f"Operation Ended by {getpass.getuser()}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # embedding_test()
    # ParameterNet_call_test()
    # ParameterNet_reconstruct_test()
    # ParameterNet_predict_test()
    checkpoints = os.listdir("./Weights/")
    checkpoints = [ckpt for ckpt in checkpoints if not ckpt.endswith('.data-00000-of-00001') and ckpt != 'checkpoint']
    epoch_latest = max([int(ckpt.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]) for ckpt in checkpoints])
    TrainParameterNet(batch_size = 128, epochs = 50, epoch_offset = 0, checkpoint_path = f"./Weights/epoch_{epoch_latest}")
```

I have also included some debugging function(s) for the readers convenience. The problem with the above code (as the title suggests) is that the gradients of the loss goes to `NaN` despite trying several initializations and smaller learning rates. The loss doesn't go to `NaN` neither does the computational graph gets disconnected at any point. After trying to debug it for several days, I am finally frustated and resorting to online help for the solution.

Thanks in Advance. I just need some help in this regard.

**EDIT** [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_ElswPqWOH8hp7gcrsRsi3GguIVxONgR/view?usp=sharing) is the link to the complete codebase. I have come to know from [mhenning's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15019223/mhenning) comment that some user might have problems running the code due to the data loading issue. So I have provided the entire codebase along with the data. To run the code one can simply download the `zip` file and run `nn4.py`. This should work without a problem.

Many thanks for the trouble you are going through to help me...

Comment: Is your input data scaled?

Comment: @mhenning  yes the set of fundamental functions as well as the function I am trying to learn are both scaled in between [0, 1]

Comment: I tried to run your code but you load some local data file with a Dataloader. Can you modify the code that it works with dummy data of the same shape/range and can be reproducible?

Comment: @mhenning There are functions such as `ParameterNet_reconstruct_test_1` and  `ParameterNet_call_test_1` which creates dummy data of required shape. You can infer the shape from those I believe

Comment: @mhenning I have added link to the entire codebase. You can download the `code.zip` file and run `nn4.py`. It should work without any issues. Let me know if you have any problems running this.

Comment: @mhenning Also let me know if you are/aren't trying to debug this. As of now I am counting only on you since none, but you responded...

Comment: I've looked into the code and the `nan's` starting to appear for the output of the `MultiHeadAttention` layer (`attn_op = self.attn(basis, g_s, inp)` in the `__call__(...)` method. In the first batch, there are no nans, they appear from the second batch onwards. Whats causing this numerical instability, sadly I have no clue, as I'm not familiar with Attention and what you need as inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problematic line:

```
g_scaled = tf.multiply(coeff, tf.pow(g_x_scaled, power))
```

In `def reconstruct_from(self, inp, basis, params):`
There are two problems:

- negative numbers with floating point powers (these cause nan's)

  - one example was `tf.pow(-0.99,-9.17)` -> nan
- very small numbers with very low/high exponents

  - like `tf.pow(8.08e-5, -64.37)` -> 2.7537892924809407e+263, which is out of range for float32 -> tf.inf

You have to somehow fix these numerical instabilities. For the first case, you could do something like

```
g_scaled = tf.multiply(coeff, tf.pow(tf.maximum(1e-3, g_x_scaled), power))
```

Although I have no idea if this destroys the math behind your approach or what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I removed the negative input(s) from support and basis. Now they are defined over `[0, 100]`. And the problem of small numbers with negative exponent(s) is also averted since I am clippping the output of `ParameterNet` to `[0, 4]`. But the issue still persists

Comment: Also, 
`g_scaled = tf.multiply(coeff, tf.pow(tf.maximum(1e-3, g_x_scaled), power))`
doesn't help... the gradents go to NaN after some 4 or 5 batches

Comment: After 3 batches, I got `loss: 7.114791735351492e+23` two times in a row. Give this huge loss to the gradient update, and wonder no more where the `nan`s come from. I'm not sure what you are doing mathematically in reconstruct_from(), but it derails the network completely with a loss value like that.

Comment: Given the parameter set $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$, the function `reconstruct_from()` scales the input by power $a_2$ and multiplies the input  by coefficient $a_1$ and evaluates the function at the new input. Finally it scales the function (evaluated at the input) by coefficient $b_1$ and scales the function by power $b_2$. Thats what it  does...

Comment: Also you might have noticed that I am clipping the norm of gradients to 0.01 in initalizing Adam() optimizer

Comment: Not in the code you shared.